# Wordpresss: How to make a "transparent" sticky header using Elementor Page Builder?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, elementor

I am developing a website with `Elementor Pro`. There, I need to have a sticky header. I want the header to be on-top of my `slider` with the following styles. In simply terms, a transparent sticky.

1. header background colour - light blue
2. header menu item colour - white
3. Transparent

When I scroll, the header need to be fixed on top with the following styles.

1. header background  colour - white
2. header title colour - black
3. Not transparent

**This website homepage has the "exact" header I am looking for** - https://en.chint.com/

In `Elementor Pro`, I created header, made it sticky and applied the following CSS styles.

```
selector.elementor-sticky--effects{
   background-color: rgba(133,130,255,0.5)!important
}

selector{
   transition: background-color 4s ease !important;
}

selector.elementor-sticky--effects >.elementor-container{
   min-height: 80px;
}

selector > .elementor-container{
   transition: min-height 1s ease !important;
}
```

I was following this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0QpeKGfvKy8

However this is not what I am expecting. In here what happens is that header is not transparent before scroll and only get transparent when scrolling. The opposite of what I require. Also it do not address the other styles I need.

I am new to `Elementor`, how can I make this work?

Comment: You can implement using this: https://docs.elementor.com/article/459-how-to-create-a-sticky-header

Comment: @MinalChauhan: I am following the same video. The result is not as expected, do not generate the header displayed in first few seconds of the video. Also it do not show how to change the colours of the menu items etc.